# How get user details who modified files in fileshare in c#

Tags: filesystemwatcher, fileshare, file-security

I need to implement windows service which monitors a folder in fileshare, it should trigger all events like change,create,delete,rename,security changes,open,write and audit level events .
Along with that for every change I should capture the user details who accessed fileshare

I am **filesystemwatcher** for basic events like create,changed,rename and delete. I could not able to capture security changes happened for file or folder using **filesystemwatcher**